# Docker Github Load Key Invalid format

Tags: docker, private-key

When using COPY to copy the private key into the Docker image, my image is able to connect to the github repo

```
COPY id_ed25519 /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

However, when I use the following, its now a wrong format.

```
RUN echo "${SSH_KEY}" > /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

I'm using Visual Code for developement, i've tried various ways of saving the key to the .env file

- copy paste with mouse
- copy paste with keyboard
- leaving the end of the file SSH_KEY=" and running cat id_ed25519 > .env then adding a "

Sample .env

```
...
SOME_OTHER_VARL="http://localhost:3000"

# Github
SSH_KEY="-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
"
```

Obviously something is happening to the format when I try to save the contents of the private key to the .env file.   Anyone have any ideas?

Eventually this private key will end up in Azure Pipelines as a secrets, so I'll need a way to preserve the format there as well...

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like Azure Pipelines allows you to directly upload the key file; so I probably won't have issues there.  If that's the case I an just keep the private key file in my local projects development environment and just add it to the .gitignore file

Comment: Depending on how you are using the `.env` file, there may not be quotes around the value. Specifically docker-compose is just looking for `$key=$value` with no other evaluation or expansion of the value.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @BMitch but that didn't work after changing `echo "${SSH_KEY}"` to just `echo ${SSH_KEY}`.  I updated the question with a sample .env

Comment: Not in the echo command, in the `.env` file. Also, linefeeds aren't supported in variables in the `.env` file with docker-compose, so if you're using that, you'll need to inject that variable a different way. Given what you're attempting to do, I'd recommend looking into buildkit secrets, or even better, have the pipeline code do whatever is happening with the ssh key and then `COPY` the result into your image.

Comment: Pipelines is definitely the way to go.  I'll be doing this for production with Azure Pipelines.  In dev I'll just keep the key file locally and copy during the Docker build

ARG SSH_KEY
RUN mkdir -m 0600 /root/.ssh/
COPY id_ed25519 /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
RUN chmod 0600 /root/.ssh/id_ed25519

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-ssh-key?view=azure-devops